# Safe to change base class in python?

Tags: python, class

Questions like this exist, but none exactly like this, and I found no completely satisfactory answers.

I'm doing an agent-based biological model.  Suppose I have a class of cell type A, and one of type B.  They age according to a clock.  Suppose when a cell of type A reaches a certain age, it changes to a cell of type B.

I have an inventory of cells.  I don't want to just create new B cells, and add them to the inventory, and leave the A cells still in the inventory.

This appears to work, but is it safe?

```
class B(object):
    pass

class A(object):
    def changeToB(self):
        self.__class__ = B
```

Or, is there a better approach?

Comment: You should probably look at the Factory design pattern rather than changing base classes at run time

Comment: @JoranBeasley, Factory is for creating new objects, not changing existing ones. This is a fascinating question, something that wouldn't even be conceivable in a language like C++ for example.

Comment: Even if it works it's a bad idea for readability and maintainability reasons.  You're probably better with a cell class that knows whether it is an A or a B and acts accordingly.  This is also the kind of code that finds weird bugs in Python interpreters, e.g. `exec` and inheriting from builtins often produce bugs because most people don't understand the expected behaviour and almost no-one uses those techniques.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes you are correct... however it should suffice for whatever he needs to change the base class for

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Some people change the vtable of objects to achieve the same effect in C++.  Of course that code is always going to be implementation specific where in Python you can do this at language level.

Answer (score 7):

While it may be safe for the interpreter, it is definitely unsafe to one trying to understand what's happening.

It is hard to find a more natural mapping to object design than a biological cell and you are trying to discard what is naturally there. A cell **has-a** age and various mechanisms turn on and off as a function of age. In the world, an osteoblast doesn't pop out of existence and an osteocyte takes its place, but rather the cell retains its "identity" but behaves differently depending on state values like age.

I'd certainly take considerations like that into the object model if I were coding such a model.

Comment: Actually, a cell can "pop out of existence".  Suppose the cell divides.  Then we have two daughter cells, neither of which is the original cell.  Also, suppose I have a class called Osteoblast, and one called Osteocyte.  When an osteoblast differentiates into an osteocyte, you are correct that the physical cell is still there, but it is now a different phenotype with different methods.  For instance, it should no longer have a method like moveCell(), because osteocytes are trapped.  The cell instance should know what it can and can't do.

Comment: You just argued my point for me. The statement "should no longer have a method" could equally be phrased "has a method that either does something or nothing depending on object state". If you find that your design relies on using the language in a bizarre manner, assume first that your approach is too clever. "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?" — _Brian Kernighan_

Comment: @msw, your re-phrasing is not equal. “has method foo that does nothing” is not equal to “no longer has method foo”. The latter implies that attempting to use method “foo” will raise an exception because the object does not have that method. That's a desirable result of the object not having that method.

Comment: @bignose, you assert that foo can't raise an exception if its class is fixed This is mistaken. `def foo(self): if self.age > n: raise NotImplementedError`

Answer (score 3):

I tried that many years ago while working on a parser. It seemed to do what I wanted at the time, so was safe enough from the language perspective, but now I am older and wiser I don't think I'd use it for code that anyone else might have to maintain - I don't think it's very "safe" from that perspective

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good place for delegation. Internally you keep the actual object type that you want, and switch it out when appropriate.

```
class B(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print "I'm a B"

class A(object):
    def do_something(self):
        print "I'm an A"

class AorB(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.identity = A()

    def changeToB(self):
        self.identity = B()

    def do_something(self):
        self.identity.do_something()
```